# What does an internship for freelance writing entail?

Tags: freelance, jobs

Recently, I had a terrific interview with a company based in L. A. that promotes events and recommends fun things to do. I don't know if they will offer me an internship, but if they do, what would my responsibilities be?

Comment: This question is very vague and hard to answer; it would certainly depend on the company and the exact position. Did you ask them during the interview?

Comment: In addition to asking here, you could also peruse the [internship tag](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internship) over at the Workplace site for more information about how internships work.

Answer (score 2):

Because you posted this question in the Writers Stack Exchange, and the company promotes/recommends activities, it seems likely that the internship involves writing. 
As an intern, you will shine if you accomplish the following:

- Take the initiative to research information, solve problems, and find answers to questions.
- Listen well to instructions, and complete work that supports the team's goals.
- Understand and communicate well with others.

That said, it is very common for interns to do tedious but necessary tasks. Do not feel put down by this. Take it as an opportunity to learn about the inside workings of an organization. Talk to employees over lunch. Ask questions. If the opportunity to do something exciting or challenging comes up, accept.

I edited the grammar and style of your original question. The most important thing you can do right now to succeed is to improve your written US English. Take a writing course or workshop where your teacher and peers edit your work. To reduce your inhibitions and increase your learning, opt to take the course without academic credit or grades. Then, in class, take risks by being expressive and prolific. When you get your edits back, study and learn from each one.